# Why won't the arbor lock engage on my Ryobi circular saw?

Tags: circular-saw

As I was putting the saw blade on my new Ryobi Circular saw my finger slipped off of the blade lock button while tightening and now I cannot get the blade lock to engage again. What would be the fix for this?

Comment: What happens with the button or lever? Is it jammed or does it move freely? Often a little tapping with a block of wood jars things loose. You might also drizzle a little household oil into the mechanism.

Comment: Have you tried rotating the spindle?

Comment: Is it still under warranty?

Comment: I don't know what happened to the button. I was tightening and my finger slipped off while I was turning the wrench and disengaged the blade lock. Now it won't lock. I am going to try hitting it as suggested. I did give it some oil before I put on the blade. If that does not work I will try the screw driver to block it from turning as Nate suggested. If those things do not work I will return it to the store as it is brand new. This is my first time using it. Thank you for all of  your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I tried the screwdriver but the blade still turned so I knocked it on the bolt with the handle of the screwdriver and that did the trick. 
Holding that engage button down is hard for small hands so I am sure I will make this mistake again. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Good deal. Don't forget to accept your answer to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a screwdriver between the teeth of the blade and the guard to prevent the spindle from turning while you wrench on the nut. I bought a used miter saw a few years ago with a broken spindle lock and this is how I change the blade on that.
If it's under warranty, I wouldn't recommend you try to fix it yourself, and instead send it out for repair according to the manufacturers' guidance.

Comment: Thank you Nate. I will try this.